# Developing Hybrid Apps with the Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: mobilesdk

I am new to mobile development.

[I followed the Developing Hybrid Apps with the Salesforce Mobile SDK wiki document.](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK)

after importing ContactExplorer Hybrid App project to eclipse its shows the error Like

**required file or folder missing gen (missing)**

how to resolve this issue.

thanks

sathish

Comment: did you rename the project?

Answer (score 2):

You have to import in the first place the salesforce SDK into eclipse and check clean project. Next you have to import the Contact Explorer in the clean project.

This blog link may help you fix the issue

http://abhijeetmahule.blogspot.in/2010/05/android-project-is-missing-required.html

Answer (score 0):

Though it's an earlier post replying so that help some one else like myself.
There are several things that can be caused to this.

1. As Mohith has pointed out, you have missed importing **Salesforce SDK**
2. Though you have imported it, configurations are not correct.

   - You have not cloned the git repo
   - You have not installed git and not set **path variable** environment variable for git
3. If you have done all these, try restarting eclipse as usual eclipse debug :)